# How can I have users only see their content in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, customization

This goes beyond posts and media. I have several CPT's and a calendar. Is there a way to have wordpress check the user name and only show content they have created?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think I can make something like that work with a combination of user login and the is_author function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author

Comment: What do you mean, back or front end? What is this "calendar", another CPT?

Answer (score 2):

In the backend, to filter all post types that are shown and restrict the visualization you can use [**`pre_get_posts`**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=pre_get_posts%20is%3aanswer).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'users_own_content_so_12761756' );

/**
 * Show only posts of the current user in the dashboard
 * affects posts, pages, media and custom post types
 */
function users_own_content_so_12761756( $wp_query_obj ) 
{
    // Restrict hook to the backend
    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php
    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
        return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
        $wp_query_obj->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
}
```

After applying this code, you'll notice that the post count is not correct: it'll show the total count and not the user count. To adjust that, refer to this Q&A: [Update post counts (published, draft, unattached) in admin interface](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53791/12615).

You'll need to care about [user roles and capabilities](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) as well, blocking the rights to edit someone else's posts/pages/cpts. That's because a user can type in the browser address `example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=POST_ID&action=edit` and access the post, if he/she has the rights to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding this to the loop

```
<?php $author = get_the_author(); 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
if($author != $current_user->user_nicename) {
    echo "permission denied";
    break;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the members plugin to create a custom-defined role for users.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/